# Airflow + Celery + Flower - Task Name is not the Task ID for Python Operator

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, flower

I am currently using a CeleryExecutor for submitting DAGs, and am running a webserver, scheduler, and worker in the same container on AWS.  When I submit DAGs to run and their tasks are in the Redis queue (using Elasticache), the Celery workers execute the tasks, but the name is just `airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command`.  How do I get these to be the args?[image]

Currently these are the important sections of `airflow.cfg`:

```
# The executor class that airflow should use. Choices include
# SequentialExecutor, LocalExecutor, CeleryExecutor, DaskExecutor
executor = CeleryExecutor

[celery]
# This section only applies if you are using the CeleryExecutor in
# [core] section above

# The app name that will be used by celery
celery_app_name = airflow.executors.celery_executor
```

And in our DAG file:

```
dag = DAG(
    'foo_dag',
    schedule_interval='0 2-23 * * *',
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args
)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id="bar_task",
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=bar_task,
    op_kwargs={"emr_cluster_id": emr_cluster_id},
    task_concurrency=1,
    dag=foo_dag
)
```

Comment: Can  you please share some code, as it's not very clear from the picture what the root cause of your issue may be?

Comment: @Newskooler - did you have any input?